# UIViewController child with transparent background

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I am not using modal view controller. I add view controller as child to my main view controller and need transparent background, is it possible to do? Now I have black background. Please pay attention I am not using modal))).

```
        guard let view = childViewController.view else {
          return
        }
        ...

        childViewController.willMove(toParent: self)
        addChild(childViewController)
        childViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
```

[image: my xib design]

Comment: adding child view controller programmatically ?

Comment: yes, addChild(childViewController)

Comment: before adding child view controller, use `childViewController.view.backgroundColor = .clear`

and make sure to set the frame of child view controller's view.

Comment: Child view loaded from xib and has clear background setup.

Comment: check background color of Xib's Subviews. Must be clear background

Comment: Actually I have only one view in the hierarchy)).

Comment: Insert your code to add child view and attach the picture of xib design

Comment: Added child xib design and code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186865/discussion-between-awais-fayyaz-and-roman-sudakov).